# Oracle Application Express Islamic or Persion Date Packer

Tags: oracle, express, date

How to implement Hijri or Persion Date Packer in Oracle apex.
Please Tell Us.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot find a pre-built solution for this, you might have to build your own.

Here are some pointers about how you can get started by generating dates in Hijri.

In Oracle SQL you can convert Gregorian to Arabic Hijri like this:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'DD MONTH YYYY','NLS_CALENDAR=''Arabic Hijrah''') from dual;
```

So, if you were to construct a calendar, you need a list of start and end dates. The below example gives you a range of dates that are from 500 days before and 499 days after today.

```
select to_char(the_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') gdate,
       to_char(the_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'NLS_CALENDAR=''Arabic Hijrah''') hdate
from ( select sysdate-(rownum-500) the_date from dual connect by level < 1000 )
order by the_date;
```

Use the above or similar to create the dates ranges. Maybe slim it down to work on a month or a quarter at a time depending how you display the calendar.

Or get the Hijri month/year:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'mm/yyyy', 'NLS_CALENDAR=''Arabic Hijrah''') from dual;
```

Then get the dates for a month (create a ranage that is +- 40 around today to ensure you have all of this months dates then filter on this month):

```
select to_char(the_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') gdate,
       to_char(the_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'NLS_CALENDAR=''Arabic Hijrah''') hdate
from ( select sysdate-(rownum-40) the_date from dual connect by level < 80 )
where to_char(the_date, 'mm/yyyy', 'NLS_CALENDAR=''Arabic Hijrah''') =
         to_char(sysdate, 'mm/yyyy', 'NLS_CALENDAR=''Arabic Hijrah''')
order by the_date;
```